# Extracting 5 digits Zip Code from a non structured Address field with power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have an address field column with street name, number of street, city,  postal code. from which I need to pull only the postal code **5 digits number**

This is how it looks this field:

**Address**

SAINT REIMS 21 RUE DU MOULIN FLORE 51421 NEULLY LS REIMS
ALLEE DES AIGUERELLES 5 MONTPELLIER 01480
RUE DE CAMILLE FLORIENT 123 PARIS 25123
MOTPELLIER, ZAC DES EMPRENEURS 34123 SAINT JEAN DE VEDAS
AVENIDA DE LOS OLMOS S/N POLIGONO GRANDE 42523 PUERTO DE SAGUNTO
C/MAYOR 2321, MARBELLA, MALAGA

Comment: Did this answer your question? The please toggle the checkmark on the answer to mark issue as solved

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to extract all the 5 digit numbers from [Column1]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Extract = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Zips", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Text.Split(Text.Select([Column1],{"0".."9"," "})," "), each if Text.Length(_ )=5 then _ else null)),","))
in Extract
```

[image]